# What is the proper way to use JQuery to set and unset Session variables when a user checks a checbox?

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a form and with JQuery post method I set a session variable when a user checks a checkbox.

My question: Is there a straight forward way to unset the session variable if the user returns and decides to uncheck a previously checked box?

HTML

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<html>
<head>




<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
var checkboxes = $(".chkbx").change(function() {
    var allIsChecked = checkboxes.length === checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
    all[0].checked = allIsChecked;
    enableMyElement(checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0);
    putInSession($(this).val());
});
var all = $("#checkall").change(function() {
    checkboxes.attr("checked",this.checked);
    enableMyElement(this.checked);
});


  $("#myform").change( function () {    
              $.post(
               'actions.php',
               $(this).serialize(),
                function(data){
                  $("#results").html(data)
                }
              );
              return false;   
            }); 


  });
</script>

</head>


<body>
<form id="myform">
<input id="checkall" type="checkbox">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="360" name="box1">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="500" name="box2">
<input class="chkbx" type="checkbox" value="510" name="box3">
<input type="submit" value"Send" />
</form>

<div id="results">Will go here</div>

<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Processing Script

```
<?php
session_start();
$post = $_POST;
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
echo $key. "->" .$value; 
$_SESSION[$key] = $key;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pass in the state of the checkbox (checked, unchecked) with the jQuery post. Then in the processing script you can check if its checked and set/unset the `$_SESSION` variables.

```
if($_POST['checked']) {
    // your current foreach loop
} else {
    unset($_SESSION);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Please excuse my ignorance but can you give me an example of passing the state of the checkbox using JQuery.  My google search didn't return any useful info on the subject.